# Put images produced by another function into subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

So I was provided a function show_image that takes an array, and basically calls

```
plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
plt.axis('off')
```

in its body. It correctly shows the image, that's no problem.

I was asked to create four images with this function, and show them in one figure, each as a subplot. I think I have to use the function and am not supposed to change things inside that function (so I can't add a new return or anything)

I'm not sure how to get the images to show/arrange as subplots of a larger image. I tried

```
fig, ([ax1, ax2], [ax3, ax4]) = plt.subplots(2, 2,figsize=(12,16))
ax1 = show_image(image)
ax2 = show_image(log)
...
```

but that didn't work. Specifically, it seems that only the last image was created, and that image always shows on the bottom right subplot. What else could I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can have the plotting functionality in your `show_image` function

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def show_image(*images):
    # get the 4 subplots
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2,figsize=(12,16))
    # now assign each images to each subplot
    ax[0][0].imshow(images[0], cmap='gray')
    ax[0][1].imshow(images[1], cmap='gray')
    ax[1][0].imshow(images[2], cmap='gray')
    ax[1][1].imshow(images[3], cmap='gray')
    plt.axis('off')
    
arr1 = np.random.randint(255, size=(28,28))
arr2 = np.random.randint(255, size=(28,28))
arr3 = np.random.randint(255, size=(28,28))
arr4 = np.random.randint(255, size=(28,28))

show_image(arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4)
```